# Android: forcing screen refresh on orientation change

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have an app utilizing Action Bar with Tab navigation which displays a listview via custom cursor adapter and then displays detail data when a listview item is clicked. I have implemented the logic to display dual pane when in landscape mode and parent/child views while in portrait mode.

My issue is that when I change orientation, my fragments stay the same until I select an item or change to a different tab.

IE: when I change from landscape to portrait, the dual pane displays in portrait mode.

My question is how do I force the fragment to reload?  I have experimented with onStop() and onResume(), but I'm not sure what method to call from there?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my ListFragment:

```
public class ItemListFragment extends ListFragment {

// initialize variables
private boolean mDualPane;
private int mCurCheckPosition = 0;
private DataAdapter db;
private Cursor cursor;
private MyListAdapter items;

// methods  
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedState);

    // create a database connection
    db = new DataAdapter(getActivity());
    db.open();
    cursor = db.getAllRecords();

    // get the filter EditText view
    filterText = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    filterText.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);

    // set the parameters for the ListAdapter
    String[] from = new String[] { DataAdapter.KEY_TITLE };
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.item_title }; 

    // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
    items = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_cell, cursor, from, to);

    // get the listview
    ListView listview = getListView();
    listview.setAdapter(items);

    // check if we need dual pane
    mDualPane = isLandscape();

    if (savedState != null) {
        // Restore last state for checked position.
        mCurCheckPosition = savedState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
    }

    if (mDualPane) {
        // getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        items.setSelectedPosition(mCurCheckPosition, cursor);
    }       
}
```

\layout\Fragment_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

\layout-land\fragment_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/details"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need some configurations on your manifest;

```
    <activity
        android:name="yourActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"       
        android:screenOrientation="sensor" >
    </activity>
```

actually this congfiguration handles landscape and portrait mode automatically. But if you want to specific changes in your fragments, you can trigger fragment's methods from onConfigurationChanged method in your activity.

```
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //TODO with Landscape
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        //TODO with Portrait
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added the additional properties to my manifest but I still get the same behavior.  What should I put in the onConfigurationChanged method to force the fragments to reload?